# plot histogram in python using csv file as input

Tags: python, csv, pandas, matplotlib

I have a csv file which contains two columns where first column is fruit name and second column is count and I need to plot histogram using this csv as input to the code below. How do I make it possible. I just have to show first 20 entries where fruit names will be x axis and count will be y axis from entire csv file of 100 lines.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', header = None ,quoting=2)

data.hist(bins=10)
plt.xlim([0,100])
plt.ylim([50,500])
plt.title("Data")
plt.xlabel("fruits")
plt.ylabel("Frequency")
plt.show()
```

I edited the above program to plot a bar chart -

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',',header=None)
data.values
print data
plt.bar(data[:,0], data[:,1], color='g')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.xlabel('Words')
plt.title('Title')

plt.show()
```

but this gives me an error 'Unhashable Type '. Can anyone help on this.

Comment: can you put an example of your csv file?

Comment: you want to plot barchart not histograms. You can't put categorical data as x axis on histogram.

Comment: You never actually pass your data to the plot. See the examples here:  https://bespokeblog.wordpress.com/2011/07/11/basic-data-plotting-with-matplotlib-part-3-histograms/ and here: http://people.duke.edu/~ccc14/pcfb/numpympl/MatplotlibBarPlots.html

Comment: Sarit makes a good point. Are you looking at counts for different types of fruit? That is a barchart. A histogram is a plot of counts against a set of enumerable values, such as number of fruit eaten per day by your sample population--so many people eat 1 piece, so many 2 pieces, so many 3 pieces, etc.

Comment: yes a bar chart actually

Comment: apple 420
banana 262
grape 255
chickoo 248
oranges 236
melon 232
lime         213
lemon 205
papaya 180
mango 178
know 177
basil         158
good 133
things 130
kiwi         127
dragon 124
custard 120   .... CSV would be like this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the inbuilt plot of `pandas`, although you need to specify the first column is index,

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep=',',header=None, index_col =0)

data.plot(kind='bar')
plt.ylabel('Frequency')
plt.xlabel('Words')
plt.title('Title')

plt.show()
```

If you need to use `matplotlib`, it may be easier to convert the array to a dictionary using `data.to_dict()` and extract the data to numpy array or something.